# Angular unit tests for services that uses TranslateService

Tags: angular, testbed

How do I have to use the TranslateService in unit tests of a service?
TranslateService is used in the service class in that way:

```
export class ErrorControllerService {
    constructor(public translate: TranslateService) {
    }
    ...
}
```

And I tried to configure the TestingModule TestBed in that way:

```
import { MyService } from './myservice';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

describe('MyService', () => {
  let myService:MyService;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ],
      imports: [
                TranslateModule.forRoot({
                    loader: {
                        provide: TranslateLoader,
                        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                        deps: [HttpClient]
                    }
                    }),
      ],
      providers: [ MyService, TranslateService ],
    });
    let myService = TestBed.get(MyService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(myService).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

During running of **npm test** I get this message

```
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[TranslateService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[TranslateService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for TranslateService!
error properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath: [ Function ] })
    at <Jasmine>
    at NullInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:778:1)
    at resolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:2564:1)
    at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:2490:1)
    at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:2353:1)
    at resolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:2564:1)
    at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:2490:1)
    at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:2353:1)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:26403:1)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:27491:1)
    at injectInjectorOnly (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:657:1)
```

Any idea, what I do wrong? My research showed me just examples with a component, but not with a service.

Comment: Not sure if will work so will put as a comment: Try putting your TranslateService inside your providers like this : TestBed.configureTestingModule({ providers: [ { provide: TranslateService, useValue: translateServiceMock } ] }). The translateServiceMock you will have to define like: const translateServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj(['method1', 'method2', 'methodN']); translateServiceMock.method1.and.returnValue(of(MOCKED_RESPONSE)); and so on...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I took this from another answer here on SO but I'm unable to find it, so...

The solution is to build your `TranslateTestingModule`

I  have mocks for the `pipe`, and the different functions of the `service` this has worked wonders for me so far.

```js
import { Injectable, NgModule, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import {
  TranslateLoader,
  TranslateModule,
  TranslatePipe,
  TranslateService
} from '@ngx-translate/core';

import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

const translations: any = {};

class FakeLoader implements TranslateLoader {
  getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
    return of(translations);
  }
}

@Pipe({
  name: 'translate'
})
export class TranslatePipeMock implements PipeTransform {
  public name = 'translate';

  public transform(query: string, ...args: any[]): any {
    return query;
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class TranslateServiceStub {
  public get<T>(key: T): Observable<T> {
    return of(key);
  }

  public getBrowserLang() {
    return 'es';
  }

  public setDefaultLang(language) {}

  public get currentLang() {
    return 'en';
  }

  public instant(key) {
    return 'value';
  }

  public use(lang) {}
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [TranslatePipeMock],
  providers: [
    { provide: TranslateService, useClass: TranslateServiceStub },
    { provide: TranslatePipe, useClass: TranslatePipeMock }
  ],
  imports: [
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: { provide: TranslateLoader, useClass: FakeLoader }
    })
  ],
  exports: [TranslatePipeMock, TranslateModule]
})
export class TranslateTestingModule {}
```

And then you just add it to the `imports` section of your testing module

Comment: good answer, but you can also use the npm package designed exactly for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hetznercloud/ngx-translate-mock